# Creating one variable from dichotomous variables with a caveat

Tags: variables, spss

I have seven dichotomous variables (0/1) for seven ethnicities/races, and one of those is bi/multiracial. Participants could choose more than one option. I need to create a new variable that would combine the previous variables AND count those who marked more than one race/ethnicity as bi/multiracial together with those who just marked bi/multiracial. I am having trouble doing that. I have gotten some help and have two syntaxes:

55F is bi/multiracial
55G is 'Other'

```
VECTOR ethnicity = 55A to 55G.
IF (55A = 1 AND SUM (55A to 55G) =1) ethnicity = 1.
IF (55B = 1 AND SUM (55A to 55G) =1) ethnicity = 2.
IF (55C = 1 AND SUM (55A to 55G) =1) ethnicity = 3.
IF (55D = 1 AND SUM (55A to 55G) =1) ethnicity = 4.
IF (55E = 1 AND SUM (55A to 55G) =1) ethnicity = 5.
IF (55F = 1 OR SUM (55A to 55G) >1) ethnicity = 6.
IF (55G = 1 AND SUM (55A to 55F) < 1) ethnicity = 7.
EXECUTE.
```

This way, for some reason, I am getting extra participants in 55G/ethnicity 7. I don't know why would that be. They should either stay the same or decrease and some would be coded as multiracial.

I also have another syntax:

```
VECTOR ethnicity = 55A to 55G.

do if sum (55A to 55G) gt 1.

compute racecode = 6.

else.

loop #i = 1 to 7.

if race(#i) eq 1 racecode = #i.

end loop.

end if.

EXECUTE.
```

This way, I'm having trouble with ethnicity 7 again, but I'm getting way fewer participants (like waaay) this time and a lot of missing cases.

Is there a way to fix one of those syntaxes so that the last ethnicity is accounted for correctly?

I would really appreciate any advice or help on that!

Comment: why do you use `vector` in your first syntax, without actually using it with a `loop` ? And in your second syntax, you don't have `race` defined as a vector, but you are using it.

But besides that: It would help if you posted a sample data (at least some example of respondents on which you get wrong results)

Comment: Also, I don't think you can use variables names starting with numbers in SPSS, so I can't quite replicate your issue... ;). Please post  a minimal and reproducible example


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Nadia_Lee_Lee, Just to make sure you are aware - you can click "EDIT" below your post to edit it for corrections and examples - we'll be glad to try and help you once we better understand the situation.